# Subtracting an array from a Postgresql array without using a loop

Tags: arrays, postgresql

What I basically want to do is mimic the [array_cat](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-array.html) functionality in a postgres table, but to subtract an array instead.

There is a function [array_remove](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-array.html) but it only removes one element at a time.

I can not figure out how to achieve this in a single query and i do not wish to use a loop. Any help would be appreciated.[image]

array_removemany(ARRAY{1,2,3,4}, {1,2}) should give result {3,4}

Comment: What data type is the array? If it's an `int[]` you can use the [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html#INTARRAY-OP-TABLE) extension's `-` operator

Comment: its of type numeric

Comment: Do you want to remove elements by indexes or by values?

Comment: by values, I am trying to use this functionality in an update query where it will update the column where the condition satisfies and will subtract the specified array from the array in the column

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is without using loop but using query:

```
select array_agg(x)
from unnest('{1,3,2,4}'::numeric[]) as x
where x not in (1,2)
-- or x <> all('{1,2}'::numeric[])
;

┌───────────┐
│ array_agg │
├───────────┤
│ {3,4}     │
└───────────┘
```

You can to wrap this query into the function:

```
create function array_remove_many(anyarray, anyarray)
  returns anyarray
  language sql
  immutable
as $$
  select array_agg(x) from unnest($1) as x where x <> all($2)
$$;

select array_remove_many(array[1,3,2,4], array[1,2]);

┌───────────────────┐
│ array_remove_many │
├───────────────────┤
│ {3,4}             │
└───────────────────┘
```

You can to use it for any array types.

Answer (score 1):

Although, I do agree that the accepted answer works, I use a different approach:

```
select
   array_agg(aa)
from
   unnest('{1,2,3,4}'::numeric[]) aa left join unnest('{1,2}'::numeric[]) ab on aa = ab
where
   ab is null
```

Hope that someone finds this little piece useful

Answer (score 0):

If you want to undo a concatenation, you can use [slice syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING):

```
SELECT arr[ coalesce(array_length(prefix,1),0)+1 : ]
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=54dd485cc7e228bba88e6332a83986e3))</sup>